# Is it possible to profile HttpRuntime.Cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my asp.net mvc I want to be able to see for example at least list of object with keys which is currently in cache and their expiration date.

Is there something i can use to do that? May be there is some kind of profiles already developed do that?

Answer (score 1):

I know of no tools that do that, but you can easily enumerate over all items and display them with something like this:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry cachedItem in HttpContext.Cache)
{
    // do stuff with key and value
}
```